# Install application from itunes

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

I am new to mobile testing. I have question: can I install a compiled application available on iTunes to download and install on Xcode simulator for analysis i.e. without having access to the source code or I have to request the programmer to provide me the code.

If it can be installed, please point to how.

Help is surely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just look for "ad hoc distribution". Also look here, the provide super testing facilities https://testflightapp.com/dashboard/

This will solve all your beta testing issues.

EDIT:
Regarding the question of debugging an installed app from iTunes:

This is what I found in the Apple docs: Q:  How can I debug a deployed app without Xcode's debugger?

A: Once you have deployed your app, either through the App Store or as an Ad Hoc or Enterprise build, you won't be able to attach Xcode's debugger to it. To debug problems you'll need analyze Crash Logs and Console output from the device.

Comment: Thanks, but its not answer of my question. My question is can I install apps from iTunes to Simulator to test security vulnerabilities ( I am PT)

Comment: So there is no way to do any reverse engineering etc. to understand the application behaviour and its vulnerabilities if one have only access via iTunes???

Comment: You might want check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7322996/is-there-a-way-to-reverse-engineer-an-xcode-project-from-a-app-file. But be careful anyway, it depends. One may read your text from the app with a hex editor (in my case this is why I encrypted the text myself) - also I have heard of other approaches - but they are quite complex and difficult